# How do I add a text shadow with CSS2

Tags: css, shadow

So apparently, in CSS3, there is a CSS command that goes like

```
text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #color;
```

It creates a shadow on the text.

It doesn't work in CSS.

So how do I make a shadow in CSS?

This is what I have

```
.Stuff{
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
}
```

EDIT: At this point, I think I'm going to reveal my whole program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

.TitleMotto {
    font-family: "Parry Hotter";
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: single;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #CF0
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;

}
.Motto {
    font-family: "Parry Hotter";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: single;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #CF0
}
</style>
</head>

<body><table width="815" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="281" height="104"><img src="file:///E|/Business Project/Business_Logo (2).jpg" width="299" height="172" alt="Logo" /></td>
        <td width="518" class="Motto"><center>
          <div class="TitleMotto">Stuff</div>
          <p>Stuff</p>
        </center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="543">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
```

PS: the image won't show.

Comment: Are you trying to style something for ie7?

Comment: @Aaron Doing it on Dreamweaver.

Comment: but you're going to open this in a modern browser?

Comment: @Aaron Chrome 48.0.2564.116

Comment: Still unable to replicate - https://jsfiddle.net/fcq7v2cq/1/

Comment: Unless you can show us a demo of this NOT working...this will get closed very quickly.

Comment: Hmm, I've put my whole program. See what you can do now.

Comment: The text shadow works fine...you have a missing semi-colon after  `color: #CF0` - https://jsfiddle.net/pbhvah8a/

Comment: Ohhhhh. Didn't catch that. Thanks.

Comment: Oh..and `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. You don't need to specify the type of CSS you're using unlike HTML the browser either reads the CSS or ignores it.

Preview it in your browser?

Click the run code button below.

```css
.stuff {text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;}
```

```html
<p class="stuff">text with a shadow</p>
```

**UPDATED**

By adding your full CSS code I can see that you have a missing closing semi-colon.

```
color: #CF0; // ADD YOUR CLOSING SEMI-COLON HERE
text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
```

Comment: I should say that I am using a .text and calling class, not using stuff that is shown above.

Comment: See my edit, and it should be clear.

Comment: @bleh have you asigned that class to the thing you're trying to style?

Comment: open your html/php in your browser you should see the shadow applied. If not check that you don't have a typo in your class and both the CSS style and class are using the same "lowercase" format. @bleh

Comment: @Aaron - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277924/2802040

Comment: @bleh Ive updated my answer, you have an error in your CSS

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for catching that,